# What's the best way to determine if one string / collection is a subset of another?

Tags: python, counter

For example, given the following problem, what's the shortest way to implement a solution?

> Given two strings ransomNote and magazine, return true if ransomNote can be constructed by using the letters from magazine and false otherwise.
> Each letter in magazine can only be used once in ransomNote.

Surely there's a better way than manually counting each character?

```
def canConstruct(self, ransomNote: str, magazine: str) -> bool:
    c1, c2 = Counter(ransomNote), Counter(magazine)
    for letter in c1:
        if not (letter in c2 and c2[letter] >= c1[letter]):
            return False
        
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is! Counter subtraction will yield a new Counter object containing only keys with positive values. If one item is a subset of another, the subtraction of the superset will yield an empty dictionary. That means that the following function can determine if any (hashable) "collection," including strings, is a subset of another

```
def isSubset(self, subset, superset) -> bool:
    return not Counter(subset) - Counter(superet)
```

In this case, the following one-liner would do

```
def canConstruct(self, ransomNote: str, magazine: str) -> bool:
    return not Counter(ransomNote) - Counter(magazine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another  `Counter` approach

```
from collections import Counter
class Solution:
    def canConstruct(self, ransomNote: str, magazine: str) -> bool:
        a, b = Counter(ransomNote), Counter(magazine)
        return (a & b) == a
        # or return a.__iadd__(b).__eq__(a)
```

Comment: upvoted, this is cool. I really like python's liberal use of these math/bitwise operators

Comment: @Alec just some new ways one learn when they do competitive programming :D, this has nothing to with production level code :p

Answer (score 0):

Simple submultiset check:

```
def canConstruct(self, ransomNote: str, magazine: str) -> bool:
    return Counter(ransomNote) <= Counter(magazine)
```

Submitted [at LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/ransom-note/description/), got accepted.

Comment: Nice one, I wonder which is faster

Comment: @Alec I'd expect this one to be faster than the subtraction one, as it can stop early and doesn't build a new Counter.

Comment: @Alec There's an even faster way, but I wouldn't call it better and it's longer.

Comment: I'm curious. you might wanna include it with that disclaimer

Comment: python3.9.6 `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Counter' and 'Counter'` , maybe PYPI thing ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 No, introduced in 3.10.

Comment: @KellyBundy ahh, nice. Leetcode using 3.10.2